# Getting the exception "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

Tags: c#, mysql

I have gone through several posts regarding this query but neither solution works for me.

Here is my code snippet:

```
        DBConnector connector = new DBConnector();
        MySqlConnection connection = connector.GetConnection();

        string select_column = QORTrackingToolLibConstants.DeviationTypeID + "," + QORTrackingToolLibConstants.DeviationTableID;            
        string table_name = QORTrackingToolLibConstants.DeviationNorm;

        string c_name1 = QORTrackingToolLibConstants.MetricID;
        string c_name2 = QORTrackingToolLibConstants.TestcaseID;
        string c_name3 = QORTrackingToolLibConstants.InactiveBuildInfo;

        string testCaseQry = "SELECT " + select_column + " FROM " + table_name + " where " + c_name1 + " = " + testcaseID + " AND " + c_name2 + " = " + metricID + " AND " + c_name3 + " = null;";

        int total_rows_returned = 0;
        int DeviationTypeID = -1;
        int DeviationTableID = -1;

        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(testCaseQry, connection))
        {
            # Issue in this reader command.
            using (MySqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (oReader.Read())
                {
                    ++total_rows_returned;
                    DeviationTypeID = (int)oReader[QORTrackingToolLibConstants.DeviationTypeID];
                    DeviationTableID = (int)oReader[QORTrackingToolLibConstants.DeviationTableID];
                }
            }
        }
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: So what is it that you don't understand? The error message seems to be plain english.

Comment: I am using 
" MySqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) "

It will automatically close the connection (CommandBehavior.CloseConnection).

Comment: @nvoigt: I have posted the question to get some solution. I dont think that this question deserves a DownVote.

Comment: On which line you get this error exactly? Are you sure this is your full related code?

Comment: I'm not sure if it deserves one, that's why I did not downvote it. There's a lot of other users out there though. What it does deserve is an edit what *exactly* your problem is. Your compiler told you loud and clear what to fix and yet you ask here. What else can we tell you that your compiler has not already told you in that error message?

Comment: #nvoigt: From the error message it seems that it is not the culprit code. Culprit code is somewhere else where it has not closed the DataReader after using it. It would be great if compiler could trace the culprit DataReader opener.

Comment: Try closing all instances of application clean the solution and rebuild try again

Comment: What does DbConnector.GetConnection do? If it does any kind of sharing of a single connection, and your code is multithreaded, such as a web app, then it seems you could get that error if two threads hit the while loop at the same time. Can you give more info on this DbConnector?

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to do your own connection pooling by creating a global connection. That is most likely the cause of your problem.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html

> Connection pooling works by keeping the native connection to the
>   server live when the client disposes of a MySqlConnection.
>   Subsequently, if a new MySqlConnection object is opened, it will be
>   created from the connection pool, rather than creating a new native
>   connection. This improves performance.
>
> To work as designed, it is best to let the connection pooling system
>   manage all connections. **Do not create a globally accessible instance
>   of MySqlConnection and then manually open and close it. This
>   interferes with the way the pooling works and can lead to
>   unpredictable results or even exceptions.**

Although you say your app is single threaded, unless it is a very simple console app, it may very well be multi-threadded without you realizing it. If two threads hit your while loop with the same global connection, you'll get the exception you're getting.